# 15 day or 15 days?

Tags: adjectives

Is it grammatically correct to say "Enjoy 15 day free berthing"?
As far as I know, 15 day acts as an adjective here, hence is correct.

Correct me if am wrong please!

Comment: We use singular in contexts like *We're going on a 15 **day** holiday*, where "15 day" (hyphenated or not) is being used adjectivally to modify "holiday". But in your context **15 days** is a *plural noun* (object of the verb "enjoy"). It would only be valid to use the singular there if the reference was to a single day: "Enjoy **a day** of free berthing".

Comment: Actually, even when pluralised, ***15 days free berthing*** is a syntactically "loose" construction. I personally am inclined to parse it as *15 days **of** free berthing*, where ***15 days*** is the "head noun" adjectivally modified by *[of] **free berthing***. But others may see the head noun as ***berthing***, modified by both ***free*** and ***15 days***. But with *that* parsing, I think I'd expect the indefinite article before the entire noun phrase: *Enjoy **a** 15-day free berthing at our new marina*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's an answer (meant with an appreciative tone, rather than a corrective tone :) )

Comment: @gotube: I was kinda hoping some more knowledgeable user would clarify whether my idle speculation about the "head noun" had any merit or not. I really have no idea.

Comment: I'd say that, in speech, 'Enjoy 15 days free berthing' (or a reformulation such as 'Enjoy free berthing for 15 days') is what you'd hear. I'd commit this to print the way I have done (the traditional apostrophe nowadays considered unnecessary by many in non-ownership, associative expressions such as this). The plural form is required to echo what one would say. Strings such as << Writers Guilds >> / << Working Mens Clubs >> / << Childrens clothing >> are common nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

We normally use a unit of measure (such as "15 day") to describe a specific thing, not a general concept. Therefore, because "free berthing" represents a specific thing, it should be modified by a determiner:

> Enjoy a 15 day free berthing.

To make the separation of phrases a bit clearer, we can use a hyphen:

> Enjoy a 15-day free berthing.

It would be incorrect to omit the determiner.

Answer (score 0):

It is not grammatically correct as written, but is easily fixed in one of two ways.

If you intend to use "15 day" adjectivally, then the noun "berthing" requires an article, and for clarity, it should probably be hyphenated:

> Enjoy **a** 15-day free berthing.

This phrasing models the 15 days of berthing as a single unit, perhaps something that could normally be purchased as a package.

If you don't intend this meaning of a single unit, but rather a span of time or quantity of service, then it must be pluralized because "day" forms the head of a noun phrase, with an understood "of":

> Enjoy 15 **days (of)** free berthing.

Comment: I'd say that, in speech, 'Enjoy 15 days free berthing' (or a reformulation such as 'Enjoy  free berthing for 15 days') is what you'd hear.  I'd commit this to print the way I have done (the traditional apostrophe nowadays considered unnecessary by many in non-ownership, associative expressions such as this).